# Metamask mobile app

Tags: metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp

From our custom mobile app, we would like to allow users to connect to Metamask and fetch their Ethereum account address(after their consent). For this, we need to navigate user from our mobile app to Metamask app. We could do this using Metamask browser extension. Unfortunately, we could not find any documentation to get the control back to our app (or navigate back to our app) with the Ehtereum blockchain address.